# how to close modal pop up forms by clicking anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I have created two modal pop up forms...one of the form is to log in and the other is to register.

only one form can be open at any one time, and i am trying to make them close if the user clicks anywhere outside of the form. i can make one of them close, but not the other.

I have shown my code which it is linked to. please follow the link below. the link does have some errors but you should get the idea.
one of the form id is 'id01' and the others is 'id02' does anyone have any ideas?

once on the link please select If you have an account please click here OR
If you have not had an account please click here for the forms to come up

https://jsfiddle.net/z6atq0ww/

the code which it is linked to is

```
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        document.getElementById('id02').style.display = "none";   

    }
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Please click the `<>` here and create a [mcve] - make sure to include jQuery if that is what you use. If you DO use that, there are hundreds of examples and 10s of duplicates here at SO

Comment: @mplungjan  this is the example which i have. please follow the link https://jsfiddle.net/z6atq0ww/

Comment: @UpendraJoshi No, i am not using bootstrap

Comment: I did. I saw the jQuery in the header. The HTML is not valid, you have many body tags etc

Comment: Also you mean `if (event.currentTarget != modal) {`

Comment: @mplungjan i have just tried this and it dosent work...

Answer (score 1):

You should make a transparent modal background that covers the entire page. On top of that place your displayed form. Then you can simply add a click handler to the modal background.

Comment: How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Place the modal and the form in a wrapping div. Make the modal position: fixed, width: 100%, height: 100%, top: 0, left: 0, opacity: 0,5, zIndex: 999 so it covers the entire page. Then make the form zIndex: 1000 or something like this. Instead of window.onlick, add the handler to the modal onclick.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery

```
$('.click-btn').click(function(){
       $('.modal').show(); //show popup
    })

    $('body').click(function(){
       $('.modal').hide(); //hide modal
    })

    $('.click-btn, .modal').click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation; // don't close modal by clicking inside modal and by clicking btn
    })
```